# Working with JWT , how to set it and use it for authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, server-side-rendering

Example Scenario :-

I am using HTML and JS in frontend .
For backend I am using Express .
For Authentication I am using JWT .

Basic thing I know is that JWT is generally set in Authorization header when it is sent back to server .

**What I want :-**

Let us assume client requested post /user/login route giving their credentials through form . Auth middleware will verify the credentials and generate a jwt token using some payload .

My problem starts here , how to set this jwt on the client side and get it back in the header while navigating user to an authenticated page where I want user to redirect when they successfully login .

Something like below :-

```
app.post('/user/login' , authMiddleware , async (req , res) => {
 res.redirect('/user/createTask')
 }
```

Assume /user/createTask is expecting jwt which it will verify before letting user to enter into the route .

So what has to be in the authMiddleware so that jwt is set in the client side in local Storage or somewhere and get it back in the Authorization header .

If there are things to be done on client side to make it work , Please suggest that too .
How this whole scenario will work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending the credentials through a form, then you won't be able to capture the response when you send a redirection response. The redirect will be handled by the browser, and your JS will not have access to anything that you send in the response.

For this scenario to work, you would have to call the `post /user/login` endpoint through javascript. Then you can receive the response from your server. Read any tokens from it (which can be e.g. in the body of the response), set the tokens somewhere in store and then call the `/user/createTask` endpoint. If you want to use JWTs sent in an `Authorization` header, you will have to call all your endpoints through javascript. The browser can't add an `Authorization` header to the request. You can store the token in a cookie (the response from login can set the cookie), then the browser will send the cookie together with the request.

Comment: For example if I use lets say xhr request to send form data , then response will be present ar xhr response (it may be some json data having token) , then afte setting this token into the local storage there , how will I send the get request with Authorization Header and let the browser render the requested page ?

Comment: I am confused here too , how will I call /user/createTask endpoint inside xhr response ? And if send any request from xhr I cant do server side rendering for that route .

Comment: You can call any javascript code in the xhr response, so you can have code which makes another xhr request (to the createTask endpoint). When you handle the response from the createTask method, you can update your DOM with whathever html you get from your server. Alternatively you can redirect a user from javascript using `window.location` - then the browser will render response from your server. But in this case you will not be able to use `Authorization` header.

Comment: So , what i am getting from here is there is no possible way of setting `Authorization` header and redirecting to certain `view` simultaneously using xhr request . I can call another api inside response of parent request but I cant use that api to render the page . I have to send some data from that api .

Comment: Basically yes - you either make a xhr request and receive data (Javascript receives that data), or you make a usual request in a browser which makes the browser render a new page (based on the response). When you make a xhr request you can return HTML and have your Javascript inject it into your current page (or exchange some parts of the page). It doesn't have to be data in JSON.